# How to make google app script - calendar createEvent() to accept GSheet inputs from cells populated using array formula

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, array-formulas

A few days ago I got help from Stack Overflow to modify my then Apps Script code used to make calendar events from info on Google sheet, so as to tick a checkbox whenever an entry from the corresponding row is made and subsequently make new events only when the checkbox is unticked.

```
function addEvent() {
  let webinarCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("blablablablablabla@gmail.com");
  let calendarSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let schedule = calendarSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  schedule.splice(0, 1);

  const k = 16; // colIndex of checkbok col
  const created = schedule.map(e => [e[k]]);
  schedule.forEach(function(entry, i) {
    if (entry[k] == true) { return; }
    webinarCalendar.createEvent(entry[3], entry[14], entry[15], {description: entry[13]});
    created[i][0] = true;
  });
  calendarSheet.getRange(2, k + 1, created.length, 1).setValues(created);
}
```

This current code worked just fine until 2 days ago when I updated 3 of the 4 cells with the required inputs to work on an array formula so that they get populated automatically whenever a new row entry is made.

The error on the app script console says :

> Exception: The parameters (String,String,String,(class)) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent.

The parameters required for this `createEvent()` as per documentation are `title(string)`, `start time(string)`, `finish time(string)` and `description`(which is inside a javascript object I think and is also a string). To ensure that the datatype did not somehow get changed in the process of creating array formula, I cross checked the cells with an **`ISTEXT()`** and all of the inputs returned **`TRUE`**.

Second trial that I made was to change the `splice()` from `(0,1)` to `(0,2)` so that it ignores the first row which has the array formula written into the cells, which also did not fix the issue.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could show me what is causing this issue and help me fix it.

Comment: What's keeping you from debugging it?

Comment: I don't know javascript. I'm making a python flask web app which utilises some google sheet functionalities, which led me to google app script that to my understanding is javascript for google cloud apps. I intend to learn javascript properly soon but currently I'm not skilled enough it to debug this issue.

Comment: Please share a copy of your sheet.

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared an example of your input data.

Comment: This is the sheet I'm working on. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nz-AXLkY3SbDm1wx1FHX65_L9RZTPzlpSWDsTYSFB84/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it worked previously, but `startTime` and `endTime` should be `Date`.

I have checked that you columns are `String`.

Reference:

[createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createeventtitle,-starttime,-endtime,-options)

Comment: okay the weird part is that before the array formula was put in place, it was a simple sort of concatenation of date and time cells, like **=D2+E2**, and putting that into the array ,still gave the same error. then I changed the concatenation result into text format thinking that was it which again was not it. now I reverted back to the simple concatenation I had initially used inside the array formula and added **new Date(entry [14])** and **new Date(entry[15])** . The events were added the the day and month was reversed. Instead of 7 August as per sheet, the event was created for 8July.

Comment: I am not confident but the `datestring` format of `new Date` is fixed and may not follow the practice of some counties. Maybe you can have a try on `TIMEVALUE` formula?

Comment: I changed the date format inside the sheet itself. that seems to have solved the reversing issue. But I have a feeling my addition into : **webinarCalendar.createEvent(entry[3], new Date(entry[14]), new Date(entry[15]), {description: entry[13]});**, this line of code seems very incorrect because even though it gets the job done, all of the remaining cells in the checkbox columns get the TRUE text showing once execution finishes in around 5 minutes. Where did the code break?

Comment: I think the code is processing all the remainder of the 1000 rows for either of 2 reasons. first would be due to the array formula having column reference until basically the end of the sheet. Second would be due to presence of data validation in the form of drop down menu which also goes down all the way to 1000 rows. The second one is not as likely since I replicated the same sheet from scratch without the data validation and it was still taking around 5 minutes to execute the script and getting all the cells in the checkbox column TRUE as a text after the last checkbox.Does that make sense?

Comment: would it be possible to add a condition to stop the script from iterating further if either the entirety or first cell of the next row is empty?

Comment: Please change the end of all `ARRAYFORMULA` from `,""))`  to `,))`; no problem with the `new Date()` expression; drop down menu does not change the `lastRow`.

Comment: That fixed it sir. Thank you for coming to my rescue again :)

Answer (score 0):

The error on the app script console says : Exception: The parameters (String,String,String,(class)) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent.

This is simply saying it's reading from data that is not in the proper data type. In this case, perhaps, try encasing the entries with 'new Date(entry[x])' for the respective start and end date/time entries.

Answer (score -1):

For people trying to run the scripts, one underlying cause might be the fact that you may be using US locale when the date have been formatted as UK.
(e.g. Date that App Script is looking for is mm/dd/yyyy tt:tt:tt, but if you click in the formula cell it shows as dd/mm/yyyy tt:tt:tt)
[image: Spreadsheet date format]

What you would do is to go to Files > General > Locale > (Country of Choice) > Save settings.

You would then reload the page and try if the script is working now without that "Cannot find method createEvent(string,string,string)" error.

The line of code to use in your script would be:

SpreadsheetApp.getActive().setSpreadsheetLocale('en_UK');

You could include it in your onOpen trigger function.

Comment: According to my answer, the cause of the error might be the locale settings. I show in the screenshot that the formatting of a value of a cell can look different is the actual value. App Script is based on the user's locale for their Google Account. So if you had a value of something like "13/02/2021" but the script was expecting "mm/DD/yyyy" it gets read as a string.